# Почему может не работать сортировка слиянием для массива строк?

Tags: c++

В задаче требуется ***отсортировать все строки в массиве в лексикографическом порядке**.* При попытке сортировки, программа выбивает ошибку: **`what():  std::bad_alloc`**.
Уже достаточно долго сижу над данной задачей, но так и не могу найти в чём проблема.

***Моя реализация:***

```
void merge(vector<string> &arr, int left, int middle, int right) {
 int n1 = middle - left + 1;
 int n2 = right - middle;
 string L[n1], M[n2];
 for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
 {
    L[i] = arr[left + i];
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
 {
    M[j] = arr[middle + 1 + j];
 }
 int i, j, k;
 i = 0;
 j = 0;
 k = left;
 while (i < n1 and j < n2)
 {
    if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
    arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
  } 
    else {
       arr[k] = M[j];
       j++;
    }
      k++;
    }
while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = M[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void merge_sort(vector<string> &arr, int left, int right){
    int middle = (right - left) / 2;
    if (right > left)
    {
        merge_sort(arr, left, middle);
        merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите код, в котором вы выделяете память. Он и вызывает эту ошибку. Запись `string L[n1], M[n2];` - противоречит стандарту, пишите правильно. `string * const L = new string[n1];`

Comment: @AlexGlebe большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в разделении диапазонов в функции `merge_sort()`. Когда вы высчитываете середину, то нужно брать не половину от разницы, а прибавить её к левому индексу. Иначе, например, `left == 5`, `right == 7`, `middle = 1`  и дальше вы вызываете `merge_sort( 5, 1)` и `merge_sort( 2, 7)`. А в `merge()` у вас вообще отрицательные значения получаются.

```
void merge_sort( )
{
    int middle = (right - left) / 2; // неправильно
    // должно быть 
    int middle = (right - left) / 2 + left;

void merge(vector<string> &arr, int left, int middle, int right) 
{
 int n1 = middle - left + 1; // отрицательное
```

И ещё несколько замечаний.
Если у вас изначально `vector<string> arr`, то почему потом вы пользуетесь просто массивами? Пользуйтесь также векторами.
И чтобы не копировать постоянно строки между массивами, пользуйтесь перемещением

```
void merge(vector<string> &arr, int left, int middle, int right) 
{
    vector<string> L, M;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
       L.push_back( std::move(arr[left + i]) );
```

И функцию `merge_sort()` я бы написал немного иначе - проверку на одну строку поставить сначала, чтобы при получении одинаковых индексов сразу был выход. Так логичнее получается. И красивее (на мой взгляд).

```
void merge_sort(vector<string> &arr, int left, int right)
{
    if(left >= right ) return;
    int middle = (right - left) / 2 + left;
    
    merge_sort(arr, left, middle);
    merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);
    merge(arr, left, middle, right);
}
```